# Using Passport.js, password is being verified in local-strategy but user is not authenticated

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, passport.js

I'm approximately following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@timtamimi/getting-started-with-authentication-in-node-js-with-passport-and-postgresql-2219664b568c) on how to use Passport.js and Postgres for authenticating users.  Slight alteration from the article is that I'm using Sequelize to query the database.

Here is the relevant code for:

- routes for Login and Account, once the user is authenticated any GET to /login should redirect to /account
- POST route that the login form submits to
- local-strategy
- serialize/deserialize operations

What's happening is that when I submit a correct username and password via the login form, the console output shows:

```
loginAttempt: password match succeeded for abcdefg abcdefg
```

Which means that the next thing that should happen is the successRedirect to `/account` and rendering a page with the user's data, but instead I get redirected back to `/login` and I get the failure console output:

```
/account: user is not authenticated
```

This indicates that the `req.isAuthenticated()` call is returning `false` despite the successRedirect occurring after a valid username/password verification.

Code here:

```
app.get('/account', function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log("/account: user is authenticated");
        res.render('account', {title: "Account", userData: req.user, userData: req.user, messages: {danger: req.flash('danger'), warning: req.flash('warning'), success: req.flash('success')}});
    }
    else{

        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("/login: user is authenticated");
        res.redirect('/account');
    }
    else{
        console.log("/login: user is not authenticated");
        res.render('login', {title: "Log in", userData: req.user, messages: {danger: req.flash('danger'), warning: req.flash('warning'), success: req.flash('success')}});
    }

});

app.post('/login',  passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/account',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
        }), function(req, res) {
        if(res!=false){
            console.log("/login: res: "+res);
        }
        if (req.body.remember) {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Cookie expires after 30 days
            } else {
            req.session.cookie.expires = false; // Cookie expires at end of session
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });

app.post('/login',  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/account',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
    }), function(req, res) {
    console.log("/login: running done function");
    if(res!=false){
        console.log("/login: res: "+res);
    }
    if (req.body.remember) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Cookie expires after 30 days
        } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false; // Cookie expires at end of session
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});


passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback : true}, (req, username, password, done) => {

    loginAttempt();
    async function loginAttempt() {
        var bcryptResult;

        try{
            var result;
            await sequelize.query('BEGIN')
            try{
                result = await sequelize.query('SELECT id_uuid, firstName, email, passwordhash FROM users WHERE email=?', {
                                                                        replacements:[username],
                                                                        type:sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
                }
            catch(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            console.log("loginAttempt: select query completed, result: "+JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            if (result.length==0){
                req.flash('danger', "Oops. Incorrect login details.");
                return done(null,false);
            }
            else{
                try{
                    bcryptResult=await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].passwordhash);
                }
                catch(err){
                    console.log('Error while checking password');
                    return done();
                }
                try{
                    if(bcryptResult){
                        var email=result[0].email;
                        var firstName=result[0].firstname;
                        console.log("loginAttempt: password match succeeded for "+email+" "+firstName);
                        return done(null,[{
                            email:email,
                            firstName:firstName
                        }]);
                    }
                    else{
                        req.flash('danger',"Oops. Incorrect login details.");
                        return done(null,false);
                    }
                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log("loginAttempt: error: "+e);
                }   
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            throw (e);
        }
    };

}
))



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```

I see in some other Passport.js examples that a successful password verification is followed by:

```
return done(null,user);
```

but this format isn't used in the tutorial, and I'm not sure where I would get my `user` object from in this case.

So why is `isAuthenticated()` returning false here after a successful password verification?

Comment: Where are you setting req.session value? The token that is returned by passport? Which is sent to all the subsequent apis?

Comment: @RohitDalal per the tutorial, the only place that `req.session` is used is when setting `req.session.cookie`'s `.maxAge` and `.expires` values.

Comment: Have u included - app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); in your app.js file?

Comment: @RohitDalal yes those are both included